# $L/K$ is finite implies $L/K$ is algebraic

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

I'm trying to prove the well known fact that a field extension $L/K$ is finite implies that $L/K$ is an algebraic field.

I'm aware of how to prove the statement if $L/K$ has the basis $1, \alpha, \alpha^2,...,\alpha^d$, then $L/K$ is algebraic. But how would I prove the statement if $L/K$ had a general basis $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,...,\alpha_d$, then $L/K$ is an algebraic field.

Comment: It would be interesting to know which definition of algebraic extension you are using that makes it easier to prove that property for the basis of powers of $\alpha$ than for another basis. Of course in the former case it is easy(ier) to see that $\alpha$ itself is an algebraic element, but you still need to argue that other elements of $L$ are also algebraic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\dim_K L=n$ and let $a\in L$; consider the elements $1,a,a^2,\dots,a^n$. If two of them are equal, say $a^h=a^k$ with $0\le h<k$, then $a$ is a root of $X^k-X^h\in K[X]$, so it is algebraic over $K$.

If those elements are pairwise distinct, then the set $\{1,a,a^2,\dots,a^n\}$ has more than $n$ elements, so it's linearly dependent: $n+1$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space always form a linearly dependent set, because a linearly independent set can be extended to a basis.

Comment: You don't need to split into cases if you treat linear (in)dependence as a property of sequences of vectors, rather than of sets of vectors.  For example, in a $d$-dimensional vector space, it is true that any *sequence* $v_1,\dots,v_r$ has a linear dependence relation $\sum \mu_iv_i=0$ ($\mu_i$ not all $0$) if $r>d$.  This includes the case that $v_i=v_j$ for some $i,j$, even if that means that the set $\{v_1,\dots,v_r\}$ has cardinality $\le d$.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 It depends on conventions, of course. I'd be happy to use sequences (and in fact this is how I teach linear algebra), but somebody may not agree.

Answer (score 2):

If $L$ is a $n$-dimensional $K$-linear space, then for each $\alpha\in L$, $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,...,\alpha^n$ is $K$-linearly dependent.

Comment: It's better to say this is a **Hint**.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is nothing more than linear algebra.

If you have a basis $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_d$, it means that $L/K$ is a $d$-dimensional vector space.  Now let $\alpha\in L$.  It is a fact about vector spaces that a linearly independent set cannot be bigger than any basis (indeed, any spanning set) for a space.  Therefore, since the set $\{1,\alpha,\dots,\alpha^d\}$ has size greater than $d$, it must be linearly dependent, and a linear dependence between the elements is precisely a non-zero polynomial equation satisfied by $\alpha$.

Note that we are not claiming that $1,\alpha,\dots,\alpha^d$ is a basis (it can't be, since it is too big to be linearly independent).  It is not even necessarily true that $1,\alpha,\dots,\alpha^{d-1}$ is a basis for $L/K$, though it will be if $\alpha$ is a primitive element for the extension.